# PHP Imported CSV data cut short when encounterng a comma

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a simple PHP script that loops over data in a CSV file, and adds the records to the database accordingly. One of my fields is a description field, but that description field itself has a comma (or multiple comma's) in it. It seems as though data for that field is only read up until the comma, however the next field is correct, so it is not as though the field after that is the remainder of the description, is is using the next column which is right.

Am I supposed to escape the comma? I am adding this data to a MySQL database, could that be where the issue is being caused?

My SQL query could be something like:

```
$description = $data[7]; //description column eg: "hello, my name is xxxxx, I am old"
INSERT INTO tblsomething (id, description) VALUES ($id, '$description');
```

The above statement only inserts the description as "hello" and nothing after the first comma it encounters.

Any ideas why this is?

Many thanks,
Simon

**EDIT:** This is solved, apologies to all as it was a silly mistake. It appears that the person who did the front end was creating arrays of content using the patter ',' to split the content. IT seems that the description - although supposed to be one array entry - was being split into multiple entries due to it containing comma's. This will be solved by using a more rare character like the pipe symbol to create our separators.

Thanks to all

Comment: Please have a look into the content of `$data[7]`. I am pretty sure that it only contains 'hello' and that the error is in your csv to array procedure in the php code. Thus, please include that code, too.

Comment: If you really have those quotes, then problem does not exist. Or you've parsed the CSV wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a CSV file. Fields in a CSV file that contain commas are supposed to be delimited by double quotes; this way the CSV functions in PHP will handle them properly.